# Удалить все сообщения из телеграм канала ботом

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите как удалить все сообщения из telegram-канала с помощью бота, в канале очень много сообщений и вручную это очень долго, бот на [aiogram](/questions/tagged/aiogram)

Comment: Обязательно через бота? Там же есть кнопка `Очистить историю`?

Comment: Это чистит историю кэша но не удаляет посты  с канала